# Python: super and __init__() vs __init__( self )

Tags: python

**A:**

```
super( BasicElement, self ).__init__()
```

**B:**

```
super( BasicElement, self ).__init__( self )
```

What is the difference between A and B? Most examples that I run across use A, but I am running into an issue where A is not calling the parent __init__ function, but B is. Why might this be? Which should be used and in which cases?

Comment: Show the code where `B` works. What do you mean by "`A` is not calling"? Do you get an error? What happens? Does `A.__init__` take a parameter other than `self`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should not need to do that second form, unless somehow BasicElement class's `__init__` takes an argument.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Inside class A init"

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        print "Inside class B init"

>>> b = B()
Inside class A init
Inside class B init
```

Or with classes that need init arguments:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        print "Inside class A init. arg =", arg

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__("foo")
        print "Inside class B init"

>>> b = B()
Inside class A init. arg = foo
Inside class B init
```

Comment: Important about this construction is that the super class A must be explicitly derived from object. Just declaring 'class A:' will raise the exception 'TypeError: must be type, not classobj' when the super init call is invoked.

Comment: Class A must derive from Object!!!!Class A must derive from Object!!!!Class A must derive from Object!!!! Repeat for three times for notice.