# Error when trying to override __init__() : TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I beleive that this error has to do with how I am passing kwargs into my base init, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Could someone enlighten me? I simply want this code to print out "1 2"

```
def main():
   child = Child(2, first=1)
   child.display()


class Base():

   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       print(kwargs.get("first", "nice try"))


class Child(Base):

   def __init__(self, value, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(self, **kwargs)
       self.value = value

   def display(self):
       print(self.value)


main()
```

Here is the full error:

```
 super().__init__(self, **kwargs)
 TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: You need to omit the `self` argument.

Comment: ow wow, thank you that is exactly what I needed. Any insight into why this is the case?

Comment: I don't know, actually. There are quite some questions about `super()`, including two which basically ask the same thing as you ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57218037/why-do-we-not-need-to-include-self-in-super), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629556/python-super-and-init-vs-init-self)), but none of them have a clear answer *why* this is so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every class `init` method has `self` as an argument to allow adding attributes to this newly created instance of the class.
Calling `super().__init__(self, **kwargs)` in `Child.init` results to `Base(Child, **kwargs)`. The base constructor takes only one argument so an error is raised.